# $p$-sylow subgroups of $SL(3, \mathbb {Z}_p)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I wonder how many $p$-sylow subgroups of $SL(3, \mathbb {Z}_p)$ are there. ($p$ is any prime)

Rather than finding generators, I used the fact that |$GL(3, \mathbb {Z}_p)$| = $({p}^3 - 1)({p}^3 - p)({p}^3 - {p}^2)$.

Since $SL(3, \mathbb {Z}_p)$ is a kernel of $ \phi : GL(3, \mathbb {Z}_p) \to {Z}_p^* $, $ \phi (A) = det(A) $,

I got |$SL(3, \mathbb {Z}_p)$| = ${(p - 1)}^2 ({p}^2 + p + 1) {p}^3 (p + 1)$.

Now due to the third sylow theorem, the number of $p$-sylow subgroups is of the form $1 + pk$ and it must divides |$SL(3, \mathbb {Z}_p)$|. ($k$ is a nonnegative integer)

So there are several possibilities due to the factorization of |$SL(3, \mathbb {Z}_p)$|.

But after then, I can't determine the exact number of $p$-sylow subgroups among them. Is there any helpful fact that I can apply to progress?

Comment: You can take a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ to be the upper unitriangular matrices in ${\rm SL}(3,p)$, and its normalizer $N$ consists of the upper triangular matrices. So $|N:P| = (p-1)^2$. That should enable you to calculate the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups.

Comment: Well, thanks for your advice, I solved the problem. however could you explain |$N : P$| = ${(p - 1)}^2$? it seems to be simple calculation but I can't get there.

Comment: The three non-diagonal entries of a matrix $A$  in $N$ are arbitrary, then you can choose two of the diagonal entries to be arbitrary nonzero elements, and then the final diagonal entry is determined by $\det(A)=1$. So $|N|=p^3(p-1)^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

The number of $p$ Sylow subgroups of $SL(3,F_p)$ is $$\frac{\vert SL(3,F_p) \vert}{\vert N(P) \vert}$$ where $P$ is any $p$ Sylow subgroup and $N(P)$ is the normalizer.

Take in particular, $$P=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1& x & y\\ 0& 1 & z\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}: x,y,z \in F_p \right\}$$

Try to find $N(P)$ and complete your problem!